# Какую функцию выполняет Options -Indexes?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Какую функцию выполняет `Options -Indexes` в `.htaccess`?

Что означает это - `Options`?

Что означает это - `-Indexes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Что означает это - `Options`?

[директива options](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options) контролирует, какие возможности (опции) сервера должны быть доступны в определённом каталоге (опции перечислены по приведённой ссылке).

> Что означает это - `-Indexes`?

если перед именем опции указан `-`, это значит, что данная опция должна быть отключена в этом каталоге.

сама же опция `indexes` означает, что при запросе к данному каталогу, в случае, если в каталоге нет ни одного из файлов<sup>1</sup>, определённых директивой `directoryindex` (`index.html` и т.п.), модуль [mod_autoindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html) вернёт форматированный листинг содержимого этого каталога.

<sup>1</sup> — если такой файл есть, то именно он будет отображён/интерпретирован.